# Write parquet data to a file on S3 with scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

Is there a way of fast and stable writing parquet data on S3 using scala?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - using Spark 
Once you have a dataframe in hand you can use `df.write.parquet("s3a://newfilename")`

Comment: I assume that a spark cluster is needed to be installed for that to work?

Comment: depending on your needs and size of data- but you can start with a standalone installation

Answer (score 0):

you can work with s3a long haul from a standalone installation if you want to, though I'd recommend against using it as the direct destination of work because of performance issues. Better to output locally then copy it there (hadoop distcp does this).